# Is there any way to disable custom fiscal years and revert to standard fiscal years

Tags: custom-fiscal-year, fiscal-periods

In my Developer Edition,By mistake i have enabled custom fiscal years, Is there any way to disable custom fiscal years and revert to standard fiscal years?

Comment: Please stick to tags which actually have anything to do with what you are asking. I have fixed them for you here, but proper tagging will make it much easier to get answers to your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looks like that's a one way road trip, there is no going back from this. Once enabled you cannot disable custom fiscal years.

In the meanwhile you can up-vote the idea [Ability to disable custom fiscal years](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DqEkAAK).